# Как в C# в элементе textbox ограничить длину строки

Tags: textbox

Мне нужно чтобы длина строк (каждой) не превышала размер 50 символов. При превышении размера текст должен переноситься на новую строку.

При включении свойства wordwrap  текст переносится при достижении края формы но, при этом почему-то в текст не вставляется символ новой строки. То есть визуальный вид текста не соответствует его форматированию.

Каким образом можно вычислить где в форме переламывается строка чтобы как то вставить сивол новой строки или как вообще сделать чтобы визуальный вид текста соответсвтовал  знакам разметки содержащемся в его массиве символов.

Comment: `Multiline = True` не работает?

Comment: Работает но при переносе текста на новую строку символ переноса строки не вставляется в текст, по этому невозможно узнать как выглядит текст. в форме

Comment: В таком случае вам необходимо вычислить длину в пискелях каждого слова и по достижению ширины формы вручную добавлять сепаратор. В C# есть функция которая возвращает длину слова в пикселях на основе свойств шрифта. Например такая: `Size len = TextRenderer.MeasureText(Control.Text, Control.Font);`